# Index and length must refer to a location within the string?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get the first 50  letters, so I used the `subString` function to get it.

As you can see, I used this code to get it:

```
<%# Eval("BannerDescription").ToString.Substring(1, 50)%>
```

But unfortunately it's not working and an error message is coming up:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

So is there any other way to fix it?

because the user is the one who is controlling the data entry! some times he gonna enter 10 letters other times maybe 1000 letter so how can i solve this ?

I tried them all but can we use it this way :

`<%# IIf(Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Length > 49, Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Substring(0, 49), Eval("BannerDescription"))%>`

Thanks.

Comment: Yes - don't specify a length bigger than the string. The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: yes i know. because the user is the one who is controlling the data entry! some times he gonna enter 10 litters other times maybe 1000 litter how can i solve this ?

Comment: Erm, check the length. (Seriously, who upvotes this?)

Comment: I just want to add a comment that this error is completely ridiculous. Substring should just return to the end of the string if the length parameter is longer than the string. That is how **all** previous version of Basic worked using the Left() function. Most of the time I am using Substring, it is to replace the Left() and Right() functions that are missing in .net. Under what conditions would returning this length error be helpful?

Comment: I have to agree with Brad Mathews.  I've been snagged by this utterly ridiculous exception several times.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe something like this -

```
<%# Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Length, 50)) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%# new string(Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Take(50).ToArray()) %>
```

Comment: .Take is not a member of string!

Comment: @HAJJAJ: Take is part of Linq and since string is an IEnumerable<char> one can use Take. However Substring is probably the better choice.

Comment: add <%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %> onto the page

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement a function that will give you a shorter version if it's too long:

```
<%
    Function ShortVersion (strData, strLen)
        If Len (strData) > strLen Then
            ShortVersion = Left (strData, strLen)
        Else
            ShortVersion = strData
        End If
    End Function
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This answer is for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), as the question had this particular tag when this answer was posted.

---

This will give you no more than 50 characters:

```
<%# Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Length > 50 ? Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Substring(0, 50) : Eval("BannerDescription").ToString() %>
```

---

Better yet, introduce a protected method in code-behind (.cs) that can be referred to in markup:

Markup:

```
<%# GetStringMaxLength(Eval("BannerDescription").ToString(), 50) %>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected static string GetStringMaxLength(string text, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    if (text.Length > maxLength)
    {
        return text.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }

    return text;
}
```

This way it is more clean looking. :-)

Comment: The '?' character cannot be used here

Comment: Aha, well, that explains why it isn't working. Don't know if this is possible (I am kind of new here), but you should adjust your question tags; add vb.net and remove C#.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your problem, and you are using .NET 3.5, you could try:

```
public static class StringEx
{
    public static string SubstringNE(this string str, int index, int length)
    {
        if (index >= str.Length) 
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        if (index + length > str.Length)
        {
            return str.Substring(index);
        }

        return str.Substring(index, length);
    }
}
```

You call it in the same way as `Substring` but it won't throw for wrong index/length. To make an example: `<%# Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().SubstringNE(1, 50)%>`. `NE` is for "No Exception".

Answer (score 0):

50 is more then the length of your result string, your code will fail in all cases when this is true. You must not provide a parameter bigger then the chars quantity in it.
Operate with the String.Length property, that will give you dinamically the number of chars in the String. So if your String is longer than 50 chars (or equal to 50) you can say you ll get the first 50 char, otherwise you can only get the whole string which is somewhat less than 50 chars.

You can use this code:

Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Length > 49 ? Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().SubString(0, 49) : Eval("BannerDescription").ToString()

Regards,
Peter

Comment: yes i know.

because the user is the one who is controlling the data entry!

some times he gonna enter 10 litters other times maybe 1000 litter how can i solve this ?

Comment: @HAJJAJ, it's a _letter_ rather than a litter. Probably be more correct to call it a character though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code snippet, I have used it many times in my projects.

```
<%# Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Length <= 22 ? Eval("BannerDescription") : string.Format("{0}....", Eval("BannerDescription").ToString().Substring(0,22))%>
```

Comment: The '?' character cannot be used here

Comment: i thinks this is for c# not for vb.net