# Using substring in line C#

Tags: c#, split, substring

I'm having problems with the substring method,  getting this error.

> "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."
> "Parameter name: length"

```
string[] nombre = item.Split(new char[]{' '});
this.listBox5.Items.Add(nombre[0].Substring(0,2).ToUpper()+nombre[1].Substring(0,1));
```

Comment: just goto the line of the error, and see values ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Index and length must refer to a location within the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398238/index-and-length-must-refer-to-a-location-within-the-string)

Comment: Solution: learn to [debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging).

Comment: Have you actually tried to debug it yourself?

Comment: you need to split this line up and debug it, then you will find your problem

Comment: could you tell us what kind of data nombre contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the values you are passing to `Substring` are not valid for the string they are being called on.  For example:

```
string s = "hello";

string x = s.Substring(0, 1); // <-- This is fine (returns "h")
string y = s.Substring(1, 3); // <-- Also fine (returns "ell")
string z = s.Substring(5, 3); // <-- Throws an exception because 5 is passed
                              //     the end of 's' (which only has 5 characters)
```

As an aside, I see this a lot:

```
item.Split(new char[]{' '})
```

I think people are confused by the signature of the `Split` method.  The following is sufficient:

```
item.Split(' ')
```